# How to reorder fields by right columns positions?

Tags: python

There is a header of table with right positions:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Also there is a matrix (rowsxcols):

```
matrix = [
    [2,3,4], 
    [1,3,6], 
    [2,4,5]]
```

I try to create a new matrix where all elements of `matrix` in right positions by `arr`.
As result I want to get this matrix:

```
new_matrix = [[0,2,3,4,0,0],
              [1,0,3,0,0,6],
              [0,2,0,4,5,0]
```

My full code is:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
matrix = [
    [2,3,4], 
    [1,3,6], 
    [2,4,5]]
rows = len(matrix)
summator = {}
positions = {}

for i in range(rows):
    cols = len(matrix[i])
    
    if i > 0:
        matrix[i] = matrix[i] + [0] * (len(matrix[i - 1]) - cols);
    
    for j in range(cols):
        if j not in summator:
            summator[j] = matrix[i][j]
        else:
            summator[j] += matrix[i][j]
        
        positions[j] = (summator[j] == (j + 1) * rows)


new_matrix = [[]]

for i in range(rows):
    row = []
    cols = len(matrix[i])
    
    for j in range(cols):
        if j in positions and positions[j] == True:
            row.insert(j, matrix[i][j])
            continue
        
        columnHeaderValue = arr[j]
        columnValue = matrix[i][j]
        diff  = columnValue - columnHeaderValue
        
        if diff > 0:
            print("Move right: " + str(matrix[i][j]))
            row.insert(j, 0)
            row.insert(j + 1, matrix[i][j])
    new_matrix.append(row)
    
print(new_matrix)
```

I have issues in place where I try to create a new matrix:

```
new_matrix = [[]]
```

Comment: cannot understand the ussage of first array.

Comment: The first array determines a position of elements (like a table header). All values in table should be by headers positions. The rest rows have shiftment to the left corner with skipped values. I need to spread them by headers and fill skipped values by zero

Comment: still don't get it at all, your code seems a little confusing, let me try to guess. if `arr = [2,1,3,4,5,6]` the output result would be `[[2,0,3,4,0,0],
              [0,1,3,0,0,6],
              [2,0,0,4,5,0]`
?

Comment: Yes, you got this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can approach this using a simple list comprehension:

```
sets = [set(l) for l in matrix]
# [{2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}]

new_matrix = [[e if e in s else 0 for e in arr] for s in sets]
```

*NB. I first converted the matrix to sets here for efficiency (the `in` operator is O(1) for sets, O(n) for lists). You can use `matrix` in place of `sets`, it will work, just less efficiently.*

output:

```
[[0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6],
 [0, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0]]
```